# how to fix 'Stale element error in ruby selenium'

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver, watir

I get stale element error in the following code when it tries to click element `row.find_element(:xpath, "//*[@id='batch']/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[#{index}]//td[5]/form/input[3]").click()`

```
def traverse_batch
  driver.find_elements(:xpath, "//*[@id='batch']/div[1]/table/tbody/tr").each.with_index(1) do |row, index|
    row.find_elements(:xpath, "//*[@id='batch']/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[#{index}]/td").each do |td|
      sleep(5)

      if td.text() == 'started'
        while td.text() == /^success/ do
          driver.navigate.refresh()
        end
      end

      if row.find_element(:xpath, "//*[@id='batch']/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[#{index}]//td[5]/form/input[3]").displayed?
        row.find_element(:xpath, "//*[@id='batch']/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[#{index}]//td[5]/form/input[3]").click()
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: you have to refind elements after DOM is modified , page refresh modifies the DOM

Comment: Thanks PDHide. But i am new to coding. I dont know where to add code to refind the element in my code. I need to refresh the page to see if 'resume' button is displayed.

Comment: This why one has to use WATIR, WATIR is the wrapper around ruby selenium binding. In WATIR, you wouldn't be finding the stale element problem. WATIR will automatically regain the element from DOM.

Comment: Thank you Rajagopalan.

Comment: The page likely has some JS code that is updating the page after the refresh, so the page is still in flux immediately after the refresh happens. Your code may need some way to determine that the JS code has finished updating the DOM (or a brute force pause) so that it’s not trying to interact while the DOM is still being altered

Answer (score 0):

It's the approach you are taking more than the tool you are using.

You are finding a list of elements, moving away from the page and then trying to go back and use one of the previously found elements.

If this is really the route you need to take, and you aren't concerned about the structure of the table changing on refresh, you might just gather the sizes of everything, and locate the specific element with indexes each time.

Generally speaking when refreshing:
`#find_element` --> good
`#find_elements` --> bad